# Gui with Embarcadero HTML5Builder and RemObjects Oxygene for all platforms

Tags: java, cordova, user-interface

Oxygene is missing a single Gui Designer for all platforms.

With Html5builder it is possible to build cordova projects, that run on all platforms.

In Cordova you can write plugins with java, .net or swift for all platforms.
Oxygene can compile for java, .net or swift.

Would it be possible/useful to write the gui with Html5builder and add the logic with Oxygene?

I would like to have one code for the logic and one tool for the gui for all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly: yes, it is possible, but only in theory.
Cordova is a tool meant to enable cross-platform development in webtechnologies, like html, css and javascript. The plugins that bride the gap between the webcontainer (the container in which the html and css is rendered, and the javascript code is executed) and the underlying os must be written in a language native to the platform, however, this does not mean they should contain any actual applicationlogic, as this is not their purpose nor something that would be wasy to do. 
As far as I know, remobjects tool provide the possibility to share the background-logic between IOS, Android and WP, but still require unique UIs, created in the respective platforms native ui toolkit, like xaml on WP, cocoa on IOS etc. 
Hovever, as your intent is to write your UI in html5, what you can do is to create apps for IOS, ANdroid etc, make the UI consist of only a webview, load your html ui in that webview, and then let the webview talk to your remobjects codebase. 
I never had anything to do with remobjects, so I can't tell how you can do it, but I'm quite sure there is something in the remobjects documentation about this.